# How to assign data to an array

Tags: solidity

I wrote a function that takes three arguments and assigns the data to 3 public variables. This is the code in .sol file

```
uint[] public rule1;
uint cond1;
string name1;

function setRule (string _name, uint _cond, uint[] _rule) public {

        for (uint i = 0; i < _rule.length; i++) {
            rule1[i] = _rule[i];
        }
        name1 = _name;
        cond1 = _cond;
    }
```

After compiling and running the contract in geth CLI. I am checking the following commands.

```
token.rule1[0]
```

returns 0

```
token.setRule("my rule", 1, [1,2,3])
```

Tx is mined

```
token.rule1(0)
```

returns 0

```
token.name1
```

returns ""

```
token.rule1[1]
```

returns 0

I want to assign the values passed in arguments to the public variables. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably the transaction fails, right? `rule1` is of length 0, but you're trying to write to various indexes >= 0.

Try this instead:

```
for (uint i = 0; i < _rule.length; i++) {
    rule1.push(_rule[i]);
}
```

`push` will extend the length of the array and add the item at the (new) end of the array.